In Xiaomi "Font & Emoji Keyboard", is it possible to add some quick toggle to turn on/off word suggestions?
I just installed Termux on my Redmi phone and noticed that Xiaomi's "Font & Emoji Keyboard" doesn't work correctly with Termux when word suggestions are turned on - the text I write does not appear in Termux command line, only after I hit space, and even then it sometimes happens to be distorted - duplicate letters (for example instead of "ssh" I get "ssshh"), etc. Also one cannot reliably use TUI apps that are controlled by single keypresses, as these are not passed to the app directly. When the word suggestion option is turned off, it works correctly.
So everytime I use Termux, I have to click through keyboard settings to turn that option off (it's quite deep buried in the settings), and when I use other apps, like text messaging, I have to turn it back on.
Is there any way to add some quick toggle to turn this on/off without having to go through all the settings screens?
